# Circular Queue Representation using an ArrayQueue

Tags: c++, arrays, queue, adt, dynamic-arrays

***PREVIOUS PROBLEM FIXED AND UPDATED ARRAYQUEUE.CPP WITH CURRENT VERSION***

```
                                 ***CURRENT PROBLEM***
```

I have gotten my items that I am enqueueing to correctly pop up in the my program but for some reason my queue is outputting the rear only.

Output:

```
 Item #0: 1


 Item #1: 2

  Here is the queue: 2
```

*The resize function is used to double the size of the ArrayQueue if the capacity is exceeded and the capacity is halve the size of the array when an item is dequeued if it causes the number of items to be half the capacity or less*

ArrayQueue.h:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_QUEUE_H
#define ARRAY_QUEUE_H

#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"

template<class ItemType>
class ArrayQueue : public QueueInterface<ItemType>
{
public:
    ArrayQueue();
    ArrayQueue(const ArrayQueue& right);
    ArrayQueue operator =(const ArrayQueue& right);
    ~ArrayQueue();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry);
    void dequeue();
    ItemType peekFront() const;
    void print() const;
    int getSize();
private:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 1;
    ItemType* items;
    int front;
    int back;
    int numItems;
    int capacity;
    void resize(int);
};

#include "ArrayQueue.cpp"
#endif
```

ArrayQueue.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
ArrayQueue<ItemType>::ArrayQueue() {
    front = 0;
    back = DEFAULT_CAPACITY - 1;
    numItems = 0;
    capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    items = new ItemType[capacity];
}





template<class ItemType>
ArrayQueue<ItemType>::ArrayQueue(const ArrayQueue<ItemType>& right)
{
    numItems = right.numItems;
    items = new ItemType[strlen(right.items) + 1];
    strcpy(items, right.items);
}





template<class ItemType>
ArrayQueue<ItemType> ArrayQueue<ItemType>::operator =(const ArrayQueue& right)
{

    if (this != right)
    {
        numItems = right.numItems;
        delete[] items;
        items = new ItemType[right.capacity];
        strcpy(items, right.items);
    }
    return *this;
}






template<class ItemType>
ArrayQueue<ItemType>::~ArrayQueue()
{
    delete[] items;
}




template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueue<ItemType>::isEmpty() const {
    return numItems == 0;
}





template<class ItemType>
void ArrayQueue<ItemType>::enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    //ItemType* temp = new ItemType;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        //front = back = 0;
        back = (back + 1) % capacity;
        items[back] = newEntry; //Problem *SOLVED FOR NOW*
        //items = temp;
        numItems++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (numItems == capacity)
        {
            resize(2 * capacity);

        }

        back = (back + 1) % capacity;
        //back = (back + 1) % capacity;

        if (back == capacity - 1)
            back = 0;

        items[back] = newEntry;
        //items = temp;
        numItems++;

    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Item #" << numItems - 1 << ": " << items[(numItems - 1) % capacity] << std::endl;
    std::cout << endl;

}


template<class ItemType>
int ArrayQueue<ItemType>::getSize()
{
    return capacity;
}


template<class ItemType>
void ArrayQueue<ItemType>::dequeue()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Item Being removed: " << items[front] << std::endl;
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw PrecondViolatedExcep();
    }
    else
    {
        if (numItems == capacity / 2)
        {
            resize(capacity / 2);
        }
        if (back == front)
            back = front = 0;
        else
        {
            front = (front + 1) % capacity;
            numItems--;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "New item at front: " << items[front] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}




template<class ItemType>
ItemType ArrayQueue<ItemType>::peekFront() const
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw PrecondViolatedExcep("peekFront() called with empty queue");
    }

    return items[front];
}





template<class ItemType>
void ArrayQueue<ItemType>::print() const {
    std::cout << "Here is the queue: ";
    if (isEmpty()) {
        std::cout << "empty";
    }
    else {
        for (int i = front; i != back; i = (i + 1) % capacity) {
            std::cout << items[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << items[back];
    }
}




template<class ItemType>
void ArrayQueue<ItemType>::resize(int newCapacity)
{

    ItemType* temp = new ItemType[newCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        int index = (front + i) % capacity;
        temp[i] = items[index];

    }
    front = 0;
    back = numItems - 1;
    delete[] items;
    items = temp;
    capacity = newCapacity;
}
```

QueueInterface.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_INTERFACE_
#define QUEUE_INTERFACE_

template<class ItemType>
class QueueInterface

{
public:
   /** Sees whether this queue is empty.
    @return True if the queue is empty, or false if not. */
   virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

   /** Adds a new entry to the back of this queue.
    @post If the operation was successful, newEntry is at the 
       back of the queue.
    @param newEntry  The object to be added as a new entry.
    @return True if the addition is successful or false if not. */
   virtual void enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;

   /** Removes the front of this queue.
    @post If the operation was successful, the front of the queue 
       has been removed.
    @return True if the removal is successful or false if not. */
   virtual void dequeue() = 0;

   /** Returns the front of this queue.
    @pre The queue is not empty.
    @post The front of the queue has been returned, and the
       queue is unchanged.
    @return The front of the queue. */
   virtual ItemType peekFront() const = 0;

   /** Destroys object and frees memory allocated by object. */
   virtual ~QueueInterface() { }
}; // end QueueInterface
#endif
```

PrecondViolatedExcep.cpp:

```
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"  

PrecondViolatedExcep::PrecondViolatedExcep(const std::string& message)
         : std::logic_error("Precondition Violated Exception: " + message)
{
}
```

PrecondViolatedExcep.h:

```
#ifndef PRECOND_VIOLATED_EXCEP_H
#define PRECOND_VIOLATED_EXCEP_H

#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>


class PrecondViolatedExcep : public std::logic_error
{
    public:
       PrecondViolatedExcep(const std::string& message = "");
};
#endif
```

Client file used for testing Functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayQueue.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"
#include "QueueInterface.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    ArrayQueue<int> attempt;

    /*attempt.enqueue(6);
    attempt.enqueue(5);
    attempt.enqueue(4);
    attempt.enqueue(3);
    attempt.enqueue(2);  */

    attempt.enqueue(1);
    attempt.enqueue(2);
    attempt.enqueue(3);


    attempt.print();

    cout << "The capacity is " << attempt.getSize();
}
```

Comment: Check the documentation for `strcpy`. You'll find it's really only useful for copying null-terminated strings. Using it on anything else is fatal. The program right not crash right away, but it's only a matter of time.

Comment: `#include "ArrayQueue.cpp"` can also be a bad idea. Many build tools will see that cpp file and assume it needs to be compiled and linked. When it does, you'll get multiple definition linker errors. It also confuses people reading the code. Rename ArrayQueue.cpp to something harmless and associated with headers like ArrayQueue.hpp

Comment: The `ArrayQueue` constructor doesn't initialize `items`. Leaves the object in a risky condition. When you enqueue into an empty list, it's beyond empty. It doesn't exist. Kaboom.

Comment: @user4581301 Would I initialize it as items = new ItemType[DEFAULT_CAPCITY]?

Comment: @user4581301 I updated the constructor initialize items as stated above but get a very extraneous number such as -842023 instead of the one digit number I am attempting to enqueue

Comment: @user4581301 I got my numbers to print out correctly in the Queue when enqueueing by setting return numItems == 0; in the isEmpty function, eliminating temp in my enqueue function. My print function however only ends up outputting the rear value for my whole queue which is weird

Comment: Looking good. `strlen` and `strcpy` on stuff that isn't a null-terminated string will still break  badly, so watch out for that

Comment: @user4581301 I was wondering if you could give me feedback on my resize function that is supposed to update my capacity size by multiplying it by two if the capacity is full. Which could be the reason why my queue is always outputting one value only.

Comment: `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` is the wrong thing to use when doing the modulo arithmetic. If you change the size of the queue from the default after resizing, `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` no lo longer applies. The queue is larger.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. One should have come with your development tools and the sooner you get used to using it, the sooner you can start reaping the time-savings. What you do is step through the problem area in your code and watch what happens. If you see the program do something you didn't expect, store the wrong value or take the wrong path, you've found a bug. The earlier you can catch it, the better.

Comment: @user4581301 When debugging it appears that my capacity size does update but, the output goes as: item 0: 1, Item 1: -8421, Item2: 3. I'll update my post so you can see.

Comment: Careful updating the question. You do not want to invalidate Onur's answer. You should consider making a new question  now that that part is resolved.

Comment: For Sure! @user4581301

Comment: Resize is not setting `back` correctly, I think. It might be worth printing out front and back ever time you change them so you can see exactly how they are interacting.

Comment: @user4581301 I created a new post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this state of the code, I believe you have a problem with the [Modulo operator (%)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-operator-in-c-cpp-with-examples/).

You are using `DEFAULT_CAPACITY` in many places, which I think you intended to use `capacity`. Having a modulo `1` of any number should result in `0` everywhere, which means you are only copying/setting/keeping/saving the first and only value, and thus only one output.

```
back = (back + 1) % DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
items[back] = newEntry;
```

```
int index = (front + i) % DEFAULT_CAPACITY
temp[i] = items[index];
```

Comment: Oh, I think I realized where I went wrong. I updated it to 50 and took your advice of not having it always be set to one and my queue actually updates now. Thank You!